# Customise Product details page

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

Can I customise only product details page without creating any child theme? I just want to modify the product image on the detail page.

Comment: Which theme are you using? Do you want edit product image size or js or template?

Comment: I am using default Luma theme. I want to edit the image and add few codes of Js/jQuery.

Comment: add new file in app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/vendor_module/templates/path file in template of your module

Comment: @VishalParkash you can create new folder in ../app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Catalog/... just follow base on magento code module. I think some answer below is help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.view.customdetail" template="Vendor_Extension::customdetailpage.phtml" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main" remove="true"></referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.media" remove="true"></referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.details" remove="true"></referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
</body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/templates/customdetailpage.phtml

```
<?php $product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php echo $product->getName();?> <!-- add your code as per your need-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the **catalog_product_view.xml** file in your module, path:**app/code/{VendorName}/{PackageName}/view/frontend/layout**

**And do your customization.**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs but anyway, I would recommend you to create a child theme as soon as you want to alter the default template. Create a child theme is quite straightforward, and it allows you to keep your modification in place even when you will upgrade your magento 2 version.

Comment: So, that means there is no other way to change the single default page.?

Comment: You can change the default page by modifying the default page in the code, but it's not recommended because you might lose your work as soon as you upgrade magento. After you can try what  Thành Trung Tô  said in a comment above. It should work